# How to get more than one score using scores api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm testing facebook's scores api.

So far, i can set a score and retrieve it.

To set a score, I use `"/[your id]/scores"` through POST method
To retrieve, I use the same api through GET method

When I retrieve user's score, I only have one score in the return object.

Is there a way to keep track of all the scores of a user?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the specifications](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/), and as far as I know to this date, it is not possible to store more than one score record. 
You will have to store it on your own server if you want multiple high scores and/or a more advanced scoring system.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you could do is to codify your multiple scores into a single integer with fixed lengths:

e.g. 
100010020 could be read as:
1 - placeholder for integer
0001 - score #1
0020 - score #2

Then perform the splitting in your application. Of course, when you upload the scores you have to submit both scores in the same manner and the sorting will only work for Score #1.